# Update global variables in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My requirement is to append the count of each Input record in the MR job output. For this, I would need a global counter, which can be used by all mappers/reducers to read it and increment it by 1. The later mappers/reducers should get the latest value of the counter. How to achieve this?

Comment: I dont think a global variable is supported in Hadoop Framework. Try writing to a shared file in HDFS and reading from this file.

Comment: Also could use Zookeeper. Checkout the docs and java codes at http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/javaExample.html

Comment: If we write a file to be shared across all mappers, won't that cause a concurrent access problem? Even if it doesn't, this would hinder the performance when there are huge number of records?!

Comment: Is your only requirement counters? Can you show an example of what is required. I don't understand "later mappers", there is only later reducers right? unless the mappers had no slot to run, there will be simultaneous mappers.
What other job does the mappers and reducers do. Do you need to use the value for some aggregation? else you could emit this also as a known key from the mapper/reducer.

Comment: Suppose there are 18 records in my input file & 3 Mappers running on it, then i want my mappers to emit the row number of each record that they processed; So, my output should contain 1,2,3....18 row numbers appended with the values. In Java, I could use a global variable to do this..but, in MR, i am getting duplicate row numbers.
By later mapper, I meant mapper-2 & mapper-3 while mapper-1 updates the count of the variable

Comment: In your case, the mapper does not wait for the other to finish. They would be executing simultaneously. If you are looking at giving line numbers, then that can be done at the reducer. Just give sequence numbers 1,2,3 for each key that comes in the reducer. To ensure that the keys in reducer comes in the order of occurrence, emit the byte offset as the LongWritable key from the Mapper.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Arun; I have to process huge data(>7GB), so i will have to use multiple reducers and thus this approach wouldn't work even there, am i correct?

Comment: No it would not work with multiple reducers. So can you let know what we are trying to achieve by numbering the rows? I mean then let us try to figure out some other strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, since the requirement was to add a row number to a huge text file, I used the following strategy.

**Case 1**

Map Reduce with one single reducer (as explained in the comments)

**Case 2**

I used hive.

Create a table with just one column

```
create table t1(value string);
```

loaded the file to the table;

```
load data inpath 'hdfs file path' into table t1;
```

Used the hive contrib jar to trigger a UDF

```
add jar <hivehomedirectory>/lib/hive-contrib-version.jar;
create temporary function row_num as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence';
```

Redirected the query output to a hdfs file

```
insert overwrite directory 'a hdfs dir' select row_num(),value from t1;
```

This created a file for me with 2 columns, line number and line content.

Comment: I agree with your answer though i would like to adopt a small change. Will run my MR with multiple reducers, merge the output and then pass it to hive. Thanks for your help @Arun A K

Comment: No I did not understand why you need a MR job before Hive. Is there a data prep before you get the file to be numbered? Anyways try it. Good Luck.